# miRDeep2 installation showing "ln: failed to create symbolic link './randfold': File exists" error. randfold is an essential for the miRDeep2 package

Tags: software-installation, symbolic-link

`miRDeep2` installation showing

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link './randfold': File exists" error in wsl.
```

`randfold` is an essential for the `miRDeep2` package. Please suggest a solution for successsful installation.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the existing randfold file ?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the response.
Yes, I've tried to create a symlink using ln -s command after removing the existing randfold file once and when that didn't work, I've deleted and downloaded the package all new. This time I moved the randfold to the user directory.  That too didn't work.
Please suggest.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It looks like you're putting a comment in the answer section though. I'm afraid that may mean your "answer" here is deleted or voted down. Please put it in a comment unless you have a solution to the probem.